# is there a way to fix this dispatch method

Tags: reactjs, redux

i'm trying to dispatch cards and remaining from a fetch to the store(redux) but i'm getting this error and it stops the function from executing further.

this i tried to remove remaining and deck_id and it works but when i include the remaining, it stops

```
export const fetchDrawCard  = deck_id => dispatch =>{
  return fetch(`${API_ADDRESS}/deck/${deck_id}/draw`) 
  .then(response => {
    if(response.status != 200){ 
      throw new Error('Unsuccesfull Requrest to deckofcardsapi.com')
    } 
    return response.json();
    // console.log(response.json());
  })  
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
    console.log(json.cards);
    console.log(json.remaining);
      dispatch({
      type: DECK_DRAW.FETCH_SUCCESS,
      cards:json.cards, 
      remaining: json.remaining
    }) ;
    console.log('Fetch Success');
  })
  .catch( error=>dispatch({ type: DECK_DRAW.FETCH_ERROR, message: error.message}))
```

```
let DEFAULT_DECK = { deck_id: '', remaining: 0, fetchState: '', message: '', cards: [],  };

const deckReducer = (state = DEFAULT_DECK, action) => { 
  let  cards, remaining; 

  switch(action.type){

    case DECK.FETCH_SUCCESS:
    const {remaining, deck_id} = action;
      return{ ...state, remaining, deck_id, fetchState : fetchStates.success};
    case DECK.FETCH_ERROR:
      return { ...state, message: action.message, fetchState : fetchStates.error};
    case DECK_DRAW.FETCH_SUCCESS:
      // ( { cards, remaining} = action);  
      remaining = action.remaining;
      deck_id = action.deck_id;
      // cards = action.cards;
      // console.log(action.remaining);
      // console.log(deck_id);
      // console.log(remaining);
      return {  ...state,cards, remaining, fetchState: fetchStates.success};
      // return { ...state, cards, remaining, fetchState: fetchStates.success};
    case DECK_DRAW.FETCH_ERROR:
    console.log('Fetch Error'); 
      return { ...state, cards, remaining, fetchState: fetchStates.error};
    default :
      return state ;
    };
```

it should log dispatch success itself only but it log success followed by an error stopped in dispatch function further

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk ? and where/how are you calling/using the `fetchDrawCard `

Comment: Whats the error you get? From your code, it looks like `action.deck_id` is undefined, because you did not include it in the `dispatch`